# Deleting the value inside a multidimensional array using Vue.JS

Tags: javascript

Good morning,

I have the following form:

[image]

When you click the 'New Item' button, a new textfield is added to the relevant section. If you click the 'New Section' button, a new section is created. When you click the 'X' in the top right of the section, the section successfully deletes. However, I'm trying to implement the 'X' below (on the right) of each 'Addition' Text Field. I thought, it would be the inverse code of adding an additional text field, but using the splice() function. This however doesn't work.

My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    sections: [{
      item: '',
      additionals: []
    }]

  },
  methods: {
    addNewSection() {
      this.sections.push({
        item: '',
        additionals: []
      })
    },
    addNewItem(id) {
      this.sections[id].additionals.push({
        item: ''
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewSection">
                New Deal Section
            </button>

    <div class="card mb-3" v-for="(section, index) in sections">
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewItem(index)">
                        New Item
                    </button>

        <span class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer">
                        X
                    </span>

        <h4 class="card-title">Deal section {{ index + 1}}</h4>

        <div class="employee-form" v-for="(addition, index) in section.additionals">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Item" v-model="addition.item">
        </div>

        <div class="employee-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Item" v-model="section.item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qs6t9L7x/8/

Comment: `When you click the 'X' in the top right of the section, the section successfully deletes.` it doesn't delete in your fiddle :/

Comment: Please include all of your code in your fiddle aka even the code that doesn't work

Comment: Apologies. Not sure what happened with the jsfiddle. I've updated it

Comment: @JamLis `this.sections[index].additionals.splice(indexSection,1)` not `this.sections[index].additionals[indexSection].splice(indexSection,1)` 

Comment: @George Thankyou! Do you want to answer the question so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this `this.sections[index].additionals[indexSection].splice(indexSection,1)`

You're calling spice on the object, not the array!

change it to `this.sections[index].additionals.splice(indexSection,1)` and it works wonderfully

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    sections: [{
      item: '',
      additionals: [] // <-
    }]

  },
  methods: {
    addNewSection() {
      this.sections.push({
        item: '',
        additionals: [] // <-
      })
    },
    addNewItem(index) {
      this.sections[index].additionals.push({
        item: ''
      })
    },
    deleteSection(index) {
      this.sections.splice(index, 1)
    },
    deleteAdditional(index, indexSection) {
      console.log(index, indexSection)
      //this.sections[index].additionals.splice(index,1)
      this.sections[index].additionals.splice(indexSection, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewSection">
                        New Deal Section
                    </button>

    <div class="card mb-3" v-for="(section, index) in sections">
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewItem(index)"> <!-- passing the index -->
                                New Item
                            </button>

        <span class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer" @click="deleteSection(index)">
                                X
                            </span>

        <h4 class="card-title">Deal section {{ index + 1}}</h4>

        <div class="employee-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Item" v-model="section.item">
        </div>

        <div class="employee-form" v-for="(addition, indexSection) in section.additionals">
          <!-- additionals of the section -->

          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Addition" v-model="addition.item">

          <span class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer" @click="deleteAdditional(index,indexSection)">
                                    X
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```