# VueJs - Duplicating form vs. input field

Tags: vue.js

[Picture of interlinkage between forms and fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wwb5.png)

I have searched this forum for an answer, as I suspect this has been asked before, but I haven't managed to find an answer.

I just picked up using `Vue` and `Laravel`, where I am building a form. Right now I am building a test to learn how to do it before I add complexity. The right form consists of 1 select-box and 3 text fields.
My requirements for the form are:

1. One button to duplicate the entire form.
2. One button in each form (also ones that are duplicated), which adds the 3 input-text fields in the form, by duplication the fields in the div called "`registration_grid`". One form may require the text-fields to be duplicated 10 times, others only 1 or 2...

I realize the code is a bit messy in its context, but it is put together by various pieces I found in tutorials along the way.

```js
    var app = new Vue({
    el: '.container', 
    data: {
        workouts: [ 
            {
            workout_unit: '', 
            workout_weight: '',
            workout_comment: ''
            }
        ]
        },

    methods: {
        addNewEmployeeForm () {
            this.workouts.push({
                workout_unit: '', 
                workout_weight: '',
                workout_comment: ''
            })
        },
        deleteEmployeeForm (index) {
            this.workouts.splice(index, 1)
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button" @click="addNewEmployeeForm">Add form fields</button>
  <div class="card" v-for="(workout, index) in workouts">
    <div class="card-body">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt float-right" @click="deleteEmployeeForm(index)"></i>
      <h4 class="card-title">Test form - @{{index}}</h4>
      <div class="employee-form">
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
          <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
        <div class="registration_grid">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit" placeholder="unit" v-model="workout.workout_unit">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" placeholder="weight" v-model="workout.workout_weight">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="comment" v-model="workout.workout_comment">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can this be done by Vue, and if so how?

Comment: So you need a separate form for each item in the `workouts` array, is that right? When you duplicate the text fields in an individual form, what properties should the new fields correspond to? E.g. should they become `workout_unit_1`, `workout_unit_2` etc.

Comment: Hi Hannah, Yes I think that would be the way to go. My expectation is that I would somehow end up with a multidimensional array for each form that is created, which I will then manage through PHP. I don't know if that is the case or maybe I will end up with one big multidimensional array covering all the forms in one. I am still to new in Vue to have a clear idea of what is possible. However, if I can end up having a unique names for each input field in each form and the naming convention you are listing, then I can manage that as will through a loop.

I have updated question with a drawing

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the form data with `workouts[index].unit` for the `v-model` instead of `workout.workout_unit`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container', 
  data: {
    workouts: [ 
      {
        unit: '', 
        weight: '',
        comment: ''
      }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    addRow () {
      this.workouts.push({
        unit: '', 
        weight: '',
        comment: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow (index) {
      this.workouts.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button" @click="addRow">Add form fields</button>
  
  <div class="card" v-for="(workout, index) in workouts">
    <div class="card-body">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt float-right" @click="deleteRow(index)"></i>
      <h4 class="card-title">Test form - {{index}}</h4>
      <div class="employee-form">
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
          <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
        <div class="registration_grid">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit" placeholder="unit" v-model="workouts[index].unit">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" placeholder="weight" v-model="workouts[index].weight">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="comment" v-model="workouts[index].comment">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modified example to only duplicate the input fields

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container', 
  data: {
    workouts: [ 
      {
        unit: '', 
        weight: '',
        comment: ''
      }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    addRow () {
      this.workouts.push({
        unit: '', 
        weight: '',
        comment: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow (index) {
      this.workouts.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button" @click="addRow">Add form fields</button>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Test form</h4>
      <div class="employee-form">
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
          <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
        <div class="registration_grid" v-for="(workout, index) in workouts">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit" placeholder="unit" v-model="workouts[index].unit">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" placeholder="weight" v-model="workouts[index].weight">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="comment" v-model="workouts[index].comment">
          <i class="far fa-trash-alt float-right" @click="deleteRow(index)"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, This makes a lot of sense, but where do I add the index in the addRow function? As it stands now, it is a copy of my addEmployeeForm, which means it will duplicate the entire form including a dropdown (left side of the picture on my original question). What I want is to only add 3 input fields in the selected form, but then it must be pointed to the right index (left side of picture in my original question).

Also, why is it important that I change the syntax in my v-model?

Comment: If you want only these 3 fields to be duplicated you have to modify the `v-for` loop to only hold the 3 inputs not the `card-title` and  `select`. But the `deleteRow` also must be inside the loop, because it deletes rows by the index. Take a look at the modified example. I only renamed the array keys to make it shorter

Comment: Hi Julian,
Thanks!! I ended combining your input with another question I found (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605867/deleting-the-value-inside-a-multidimensional-array-using-vue-js)